# In C, how to create a function that, given a string literal as a parameter, returns a char*? (Without allocating new memory on the heap)

Tags: c, pointers, string-literals

Desired outcome:

`utilityfun("&xxx")` must return a pointer to "xxx".

`utilityfun("xxx")` must return a pointer to "*xxx".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* utilityfun(char *s)
{
        if(*s=='&')
                return s+1; // this case works fine
        else
        {
                char r[strlen(s)+2];
                memset(r,'*',1);
                strcpy(r+1,s);
                char* p=r;
                return p; // !!! p is local to this stack frame!
        }
}


void main()
{
    char* q=utilityfun("xxx");
    printf("%p\n",q); 
    printf("%s\n",q); // *xxx  It seems to work if I use q right way, but...
    utilityfun("eee");
    printf("%s\n",q); // *eee
}
```

Allocating a new char array on the heap is the only way?

My problem with that is: being `utilityfun` a utility function, I don't want to have to free memory outside of it each time I use it. Is there a way?

Comment: Doing `p=r` makes `p` points to the stack since `r` was...

Comment: Sure, that's my problem. But what if I use q right away? For example, in main, I could do something like this:  `char str[5];
strcpy(str,uutilityfun("xxx"));
mem(&str[0],10,"str[0]");`   How dangerous is this? What is a good alternative? Using malloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that it only needs to work with string literals… you can use a macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define utilityfun(x) utilityfun_("*" x)

char *utilityfun_(char *s) {
    if (s[0] == '*' && s[1] == '&') {
        return s + 2;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *a = utilityfun("eee");
    char *b = utilityfun("&fff");
    // Prints "a = *eee; b = fff;\n"
    printf("a = %s; b = %s;\n", a, b);
}
```

This is a pretty ugly hack but it doesn't allocate memory at runtime. It only works with string literals, because it uses string literal concatenation to avoid allocating—in C, `"abc" "def"` becomes `"abcdef"`. This does not work with non-literals, e.g., `"abc" x` does not work.

Comment: isn't the `s[0] == '*'` test superfluous.... (besides, interesting idea!)

Comment: Great answer! It's exactly what I was looking for! Many many thanks Dietrich!

Comment: could an alternative solution be declaring a static array inside utilityfun_?

Comment: That has two problems: (1) the function would always return the same pointer, so if you call it twice, the second call will overwrite the first, and (2) the allocation size is fixed, so it won't work for longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a public variable then fill and return it in function :

```
char *out;

char* utilityfun(char *s)
{
        if(*s=='&')
                return s+1; // this case works fine
        else
        {
                // char r[strlen(s)+2];   // You cannot use of non-constant array length
                char *r = (char*)malloc(strlen(s) + 2);
                memset(r,'*',1);
                strcpy(r+1,s);
                strcpy(out, r);          // Instead of char* p=r; use of this
                free(r);                 // Then free r
                return out;
        }
}
```

In main function, allocate it to get the right size :

```
void main()
{
    char *input = "xxx";

    out = (char*)malloc(strlen(input) + 1);

    char* q=utilityfun(input);

    printf("%p\n",q); 
    printf("%s\n",q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Dietrich's solution is the best for my problem, but would this be an alternative solution? Are there major drawbacks to this approach?

```
{
    static char arr[10];
    strncpy(arr,s,9);
    if(arr[0]=='&')
    {
        return arr+1;
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(&arr[1],&arr[0],strlen(s)+1);
        arr[0]='*';
        return arr;
    }
}
```